# ScrollViewer is visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility but this doesn't work when you set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to "Hidden".

What I'm trying to achieve is knowing if a `ScrollViewer` should be visible but without showing the `ScrollViewer`. Then bind that result to show the buttons that control the `ScrollViewer` (in this case the `StackPanel below).

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="Scroll">
   .....
</ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Scroll, Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}">
   <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="..."/>
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="..."/>
</StackPanel >
```

Comment: You set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`, which, I think, will be equal to `Visibility.Collapsed` (not `Hidden`) and will not take any space in layout.

Comment: Yes and that's the desired effect, but when it is visible I want to show the buttons and not the scrollviewer

Comment: You may need to create your own ScrollViewer control that still does the measuring required, but does not show a ScrollViewer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers but finally got a workaround a bit easier, instead of binding the visibility from the `StackPanel` of the buttons just call a `ScrollChanged` in the `ScrollViewer` and then in code check for the `ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and change visibilities depending on the result.

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="Scroll" ScrollChanged="Scroll_ScrollChanged">
       .....
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="BPanel" Visibility="Hidden">
       <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="..."/>
       <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="..."/>
    </StackPanel >
```

C#

```
private void Scroll_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)sender;
   if(scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Auto)
   {
      if (scroll.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
      {
         scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
         BPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to control the way the ScrollViewer (or any control, really) is laid out, consider using a `ControlTemplate`, which is accesible in any Control's `Template` property. as this will allow you to bind to the object itself and values passed in to it, and provide such templating. This may, however, involve needing to deal with the computations to show the exact part of your control which is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get  what you want by simple adding up the width of content elements inside `ScrollViewer`, e.g. if you have a `StackPanel` (with `Orientation=Horizontal`) inside `ScrollViewer` then add up the width of each child element in the `StackPanel` and compare it with `ActualWidth` of `ScrollViewer`. if the sum is less greater than the `ActualWidth` of `ScrollViewer` then you need to scroll it.

For more details refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/214442/A-Scrolling-Area-with-Only-Scroll-Buttons)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the scroll viewer property values can be stale until the next layout pass. It's code-behind in my simple example below but this does work the way you want.

I create a dependency property called "ShowScrollButtons". You can probably watch for extent and viewport size changes and automatically recompute the property.

When the scroll content size changes, I trigger a re-evaluate of ShowScrollButtons. Note the call to UpdateLayout to make sure the extent and viewport sizes are up-to-date.  Again, it's a sample so I'm only checking the Width here for left/right scroll buttons

```
private void UpdateScrollButtonVis()
{
    UpdateLayout();
    ShowScrollButtons = (Scroll.ExtentHeight > Scroll.ViewportWidth);
}
```

In XAML...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolvis"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="theGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0"  Width="100" Height="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Scroll">
        <Canvas x:Name="theCanvas"  Width="300" Height="300" Background="Green"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="{Binding ShowScrollButtons,Converter={StaticResource boolvis}}">
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel >
    <Button x:Name="toggle" Grid.Row="2"  Height="25" Width="100" Click="toggle_Click">Toggle</Button>
</Grid>
```

**Update:**

How about a new approach works with multiple scroll viewers and StackPanels without code-behind.

Use an Attached Property to control the external button visibility:

```
public class ScrollViewWatcher
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalButtonVisibility = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
       "HorizontalButtonVisibility",
       typeof(Visibility),
       typeof(ScrollViewWatcher),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible,
           FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure)
     );

    public static Visibility GetHorizontalButtonVisiblity(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Visibility)element.GetValue(HorizontalButtonVisibility);
    }

    public static void SetHorizontalButtonVisibility(UIElement element, Visibility value)
    {
        element.SetValue(HorizontalButtonVisibility, value);

        ScrollViewer sv = element as ScrollViewer;
        if (sv != null)
        {
            sv.ScrollChanged -= sv_ScrollChanged;
            sv.ScrollChanged += sv_ScrollChanged;
        }
    }

    static void sv_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (sv != null)
        {
            var vis = sv.ExtentHeight > sv.ViewportWidth ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            sv.SetValue(HorizontalButtonVisibility, vis);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in XAML, bind to the appropriate ScrollViewer like this:

```
<ScrollViewer 
    x:Name="sv1" local:ScrollViewWatcher.HorizontalButtonVisibility="Visible"  
    Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
    <Canvas x:Name="theCanvas"  Width="300" Height="300" Background="Green"/>
</ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=sv1,Path=(local:ScrollViewWatcher.HorizontalButtonVisibility), Mode=OneWay}">
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel >
```

This works great in my test.  This was a fun challenge. Maybe someone can enlighten us with a better approach but I'm pretty happy with this.

Comment: My problem is that all this code is inside ItemsControl's so I have several ScrollViewers and StackPanels with the buttons, with your approach how would I know which Scroll is?

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar but without binding the visibility. Thank you!